# PHP Unset Command in If Statement Not Working

Tags: php

I would like to unset an HTTP Posted key from the array after it echoes the "1" result, but the unset doesn't seem to work. How can I fix this?

```
$keylist = array('HHH', 'GGG');

if (in_array($_POST["keys"], $keylist)){ 
    echo "1"; 
    unset($keylist[$_POST["keys"]]);
} else {
    echo "0" ;
}
```

Appreciate any help,

Hobbyist

Comment: Which array do you want the removal to come from?  `$_POST['keys']` or `$keylist`?

Comment: What do you desire your code to do that it doesn't do at the moment?

Comment: does `$_POST['keys']` has array or key name

Answer (score 1):

Your unsetting $keylist not $_POST

```
unset($_POST["keys"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong array key for unsetting (You're trying to unset $keylist["HHH"], not, say, $keylist[0]) - you'll need to retrieve the key from the array, and then unset that specifically in order to remove it from the keylist.

```
$index = array_search($_POST["keys"], $keylist);
if($index!==false) { //YES, NOT DOUBLE EQUALS
    unset($keylist[$index));
}
```

If $_POST["keys"] is an array of keys, you'll need to use array_keys with a search_value instead.

Array_search documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

Array_keys documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php

EDIT: Adding a full, working example.

```
<?
$_POST["keys"]="asdjkgldshglsjhgsdlhgsdlghsdlghsdlgh";
$keylist=array("asdjkgldshglsjhgsdlhgsdlghsdlghsdlgh","derp2");
if(in_array($_POST["keys"], $keylist)) {
    $indexToRemove = array_search($_POST["keys"], $keylist);
    echo "1";
    print_r($keylist);
    unset($keylist[$indexToRemove]);
    print_r($keylist);
} else {
    echo "0";
    print_r($keylist);
}
?>
```

Another example, this time checking the index itself to see if it is not false:

```
<?
$_POST["keys"]="asdjkgldshglsjhgsdlhgsdlghsdlghsdlgh";
$keylist=array("asdjkgldshglsjhgsdlhgsdlghsdlghsdlgh","derp2");
$indexToRemove = array_search($_POST["keys"], $keylist);
if($indexToRemove!==false) {
    echo "1";
    print_r($keylist);
    unset($keylist[$indexToRemove]);
    print_r($keylist);
} else {
    echo "0";
    print_r($keylist);
}
?>
```

Output:

```
1Array ( [0] => asdjkgldshglsjhgsdlhgsdlghsdlghsdlgh [1] => derp2 ) Array ( [1] => derp2 )
```

I realize now that I only had one = on the $index!==false check - the reason you need two is because $index is 0 if you're removing the first element of an array.  Per PHP documentation,

```
Warning
This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a non-Boolean
value which evaluates to FALSE. Please read the section on Booleans for more 
information. Use the === operator for testing the return value of this function.
```

Comment: I've tried to search to get the key number in the array and then unset that but it still won't remove the value from the array

Comment: Is your $_POST["keys"] variable an array, or a string?  If it's an array, array_search won't behave correctly.  If it's a string, it should be unsetting, and I'd like to see your code.

Comment: `<?php

$keylist = array('CzcQTFrXTW3HGPCuS8Ss5DUb', 'gtB9DXxvj7QnvMDAQHuB8H7L');
$index = array_search($_POST["keys"], $keylist);

if (in_array($_POST["keys"], $keylist))
 
 { 
 
echo "1"; 
 
if($index!=false) {
    unset($keylist[$index]));
}

}

 
 else 
 
 {
  
 echo "0" ;
 
 }
 
 ?>
 
 ` That's the full code, appreciate the help

Comment: Testing a few things, I'll update my answer with working code given this information.  EDIT: What is $_POST["keys"]?  An array of keys, or a single key?  What's setting $_POST["keys"], and what is it being set to?

Comment: $_POST["keys"] is a user entering a key, for example the user will enter 'CzcQTFrXTW3HGPCuS8Ss5DUb', the script will then echo a 1 and remove what they entered off the list, if they enter anything but a set array value it will echo 0

Comment: Okay, perfect.  I'm updating my answer now with a full, working example.

Comment: @HobbyistOrtho Please check my answer now, it contains two examples that work and explanation for what was going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

`in_array($_POST["keys"], $keylist)` checks if the posted value `$_POST["keys"]` is present as a value in `$keylist`, but `unset($keylist[$_POST["keys"]])` uses `$_POST["keys"]` as the key in `$keylist` to unset something.

Since `in_array()` returns `true`, the posted value is present in the array `$keylist`. But you can't do `unset($keylist['GGG'])` because that value is not set.

A simple solution is to use the same values as keys too:

```
$keylist = array('HHH', 'GGG');
$keylist = array_combine($keylist, $keylist);
```

More about [array_combine()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php).

Comment: I used the command $keylist = array_combine($keylist, $keylist); under the array of values, I then added unset($keylist[$_POST["keys"]]) to the true condition of the if (under echo "1";) yet still doesn't unset the value?

Answer (score 0):

Your array have keys. So "HHH" in keylist is $keylist[0] and not $keylist['HHH']. You can not unset it because you have to define the array key instead of the array value.
Try to search for the array value like this:

array_search($_POST["keys"], $keylist)

This will return the array key for you or false if its not found. Your full code should like look like:

```
echo "1"; 
$arrkey = array_search($_POST["keys"], $keylist);
if( $arrkey !== false ){
unset($keylist[$arrkey]);
}
```

Here the PHP Manual for the array_search function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

Comment: Thanks Mike, I tried the code you write above in the true condition of the if statement but it still doesn't unset the value from the array

Comment: i have posted the part of your code. I tested it succesfull.  Be carefull. dont use if( $arrkey == true ) or if( $arrkey ).  Use if( $arrkey !== false ) This part is important